# Take Average of two columns sql

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
Select Age,

       (select avg(ShoeSize) from [dbo].[Transaction] t2 where t2.age = t1.Age and t2.ChildGender='Male') as avg_male,
       (select avg(ShoeSize) from [dbo].[Transaction] t2 where t2.age = t1.Age and t2.ChildGender='Female') as avg_female

from [dbo].[Transaction] t1

group by Age ORDER BY Age
```

Hi, I have two columns avg_male and avg_female how do I take the average of the two columns and display in the third. Please help

Comment: take a look at my answer. To do the third column, you can simply do the same average calculation without taking into account gender in the where clause.

Answer (score 3):

Just use simple mathematics:

```
select avg_male
,      avg_female
,      ( avg_male + avg_female) / 2
from   transaction
```

Edit:

I think this should work. Haven't SQLFiddle, but it should do:

```
Select Age
,      sum(case when ChildGender='Male' then ShoeSize else 0 end) / sum(case when ChildGender='Male' then 1 else 0 end) as avg_male,
,      sum(case when ChildGender='Female' then ShoeSize else 0 end) / sum(case when ChildGender='Female' then 1 else 0 end) as avg_male,
,      avg(ShoeSize) as avg_both
from   [dbo].[Transaction] t1
group
by     Age
ORDER
BY     Age
```

Comment: Please could you tell in the same query that i have written as my real table is Transaction

Comment: What about weighted averages?  If there are 10 males and 100 females, for example.

Comment: @MatBailie: that wasn't in the question, but I think the answer from Matthias Meid is correct on that.

Comment: @MatBailie: you could take the two `sum`s from by answer and divide it by two.

Comment: @PatrickHofman - That's an unweighted average, not a weighted average.

Comment: @MatBailie: I think my example has both: the first is the unweighted average, the second is the weighted variant.

Answer (score 2):

Using `(avg(x) + avg(y)) / 2`, both columns would have the same weight, **even if they didn't have the same amount of entries**. If you want to take the total arithmetic average of *all values in both columns*, you need to sum them up and divide them by their *total count*:

```
SELECT (sum_male + sum_female) / (count_male + count_female)
    FROM transaction
```

The `SUM` and `COUNT` aggregate functions help you to compute these values:

```
(select sum(ShoeSize) from [dbo].[Transaction] t2 where t2.age = t1.Age and t2.ChildGender='Male') as sum_male,
(select sum(ShoeSize) from [dbo].[Transaction] t2 where t2.age = t1.Age and t2.ChildGender='Female') as sum_female
(select count(ShoeSize) from [dbo].[Transaction] t2 where t2.age = t1.Age and t2.ChildGender='Male') as count_male,
(select count(ShoeSize) from [dbo].[Transaction] t2 where t2.age = t1.Age and t2.ChildGender='Female') as count_female
```

Provided **all records are either of `Male` or `Female` `ChildGender`**, [TheOneWhoPrograms's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21824859/17713) is an even more straightforward solution.

Comment: Thanks for the reference to my answer. I have modified my answer to take into consideration if his table has more than only male and female.

Comment: Why not use the avg function?

Comment: @vini Let's assume you've got 20 boys, all aged 10, and 30 girls, all aged 5, in your DB. `(avg(boys) + avg(girls)) / 2 = (10 + 5) / 2 = 7.5`, whereas `(sum(boys) + sum(girls)) / (count(boys) + count(girls)) = (200 + 150) / (20 + 30) = 7`. Unlike the former, the latter calculation takes into account the fact that there are more girls than boys, resulting in a lower average age. See the difference? There is no *right* or *wrong*, there are two different formulas and it's up to you to decide which one is what you need.

Answer (score 2):

The following should work. It does the same thing as you do, but the third column does the average without taking into consideration the gender.

If there are only MALE or FEMALE children

```
Select Age,

   (select avg(ShoeSize) from [dbo].[Transaction] t2 where t2.age = t1.Age and     t2.ChildGender='Male') as avg_male,
   (select avg(ShoeSize) from [dbo].[Transaction] t2 where t2.age = t1.Age and t2.ChildGender='Female') as avg_female
   (select avg(ShoeSize) from [dbo].[Transaction] t2 where t2.age = t1.Age as avg_avg
from [dbo].[Transaction] t1

group by Age ORDER BY Age
```

If there are some that are NOT MALE OR FEMALE and you only want the average of male and female

```
Select Age,

   (select avg(ShoeSize) from [dbo].[Transaction] t2 where t2.age = t1.Age and     t2.ChildGender='Male') as avg_male,
   (select avg(ShoeSize) from [dbo].[Transaction] t2 where t2.age = t1.Age and t2.ChildGender='Female') as avg_female
   (select avg(ShoeSize) from [dbo].[Transaction] t2 where t2.age = t1.Age AND (t2.ChildGender='Male' OR t2.ChildGender='Female') as avg_avg
from [dbo].[Transaction] t1

group by Age ORDER BY Age
```

Answer (score 2):

A useful piece of knowledge is that `NULL` is excluded from aggregates.

This means that `AVG({1, 2, 3, NULL})` is 2.  *(1 + 2 + 3) / (3)*.

The following use of `CASE` to *NULLify* certain records can then simplify things.

```
SELECT
  Age,
  AVG(CASE WHEN ChildGender = 'Male'   THEN ShoeSize ELSE NULL END)   AS avgMale,
  AVG(CASE WHEN ChildGender = 'Female' THEN ShoeSize ELSE NULL END)   AS avgFemale,
  AVG(                                      ShoeSize              )   AS avgAll
FROM
  [dbo].[Transaction]
GROUP BY
  Age
```

This trick also works with `SUM()`, `COUNT()`, etc.

Answer (score 0):

```
;with CTE AS
(
select 0 avg_male ,avg(ShoeSize) avg_female from [Transaction] ChildGender='Female'
union
select avg(ShoeSize) avg_male ,0 avg_female from [Transaction] ChildGender='Male'
)
select 
SUM(avg_male) avg_male,SUM(avg_female),(SUM(avg_male) avg_male+SUM(avg_female))/2 Total
from CTE
```